# Stub -[NSDate init]

Tags: objective-c, mocking, stub, objective-c-category, method-swizzling

Stubbing NSDate to return a mock date can easily be done using category except for -[NSDate init]. -[NSDate init] is not called unlike other methods. class_addMethod does not help. method_exchangeImplementations, method_setImplementation on -[NSDate init] actually change -[NSObject init] but no effect on -[NSDate init].

```
[NSDate setMockDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:0]];
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"%@", date1);
NSLog(@"%.0f", [date1 timeIntervalSinceNow]);

// _replacement_Method is not called!
NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", date2);
NSLog(@"%.0f", [date2 timeIntervalSinceNow]);

// _replacement_Method is called
NSObject *object = [[NSObject alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", object);

// A class with empty implementation to test inherited init from NSObject
// _replacement_Method is called by -[MyObject init]
MyObject *myobject = [[MyObject alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", myobject);
```

The output is

```
2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
-0
2014-11-26 14:43:26 +0000
438705806
<NSObject: 0x7fbc50e19d90>
<MyObject: 0x7fbc50e4ad30>
```

NSDate+Mock.m

```
#import "NSDate+Mock.h"

#import <mach/clock.h>
#import <mach/mach.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static NSTimeInterval sTimeOffset;
static IMP __original_Method_Imp;

id _replacement_Method(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    return ((id(*)(id,SEL))__original_Method_Imp)(self, _cmd);
}

@implementation NSDate (Mock)

+ (NSObject *)lock
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static NSObject *lock;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        lock = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    });
    return lock;
}

+ (void)setMockDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Method m1 = class_getInstanceMethod([NSDate class], @selector(init));
        Method m2 = class_getInstanceMethod([NSDate class], @selector(initMock));
//        method_exchangeImplementations(m1, m2);
//        class_addMethod([NSDate class], @selector(init), (IMP)_replacement_Method, "@@:");
        __original_Method_Imp = method_setImplementation(m1, (IMP)_replacement_Method);
    });

    @synchronized([self lock]) {
        sTimeOffset = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - [self trueTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    }
}

+ (NSTimeInterval)mockTimeOffset
{
    @synchronized([self lock]) {
        return sTimeOffset;
    }
}

+ (NSTimeInterval)trueTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
{
    clock_serv_t cclock;
    mach_timespec_t mts;
    host_get_clock_service(mach_host_self(), CALENDAR_CLOCK, &cclock);
    clock_get_time(cclock, &mts);
    mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), cclock);
    NSTimeInterval now = mts.tv_sec + mts.tv_nsec * 1e-9 - NSTimeIntervalSince1970;
    return now;
}

+ (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
{
    return [self trueTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + [self mockTimeOffset];
}

+ (instancetype)date
{
    return [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
}

+ (instancetype)dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(NSTimeInterval)secs
{
    return [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:secs];
}

//- (instancetype)init
//{
//    self = [super init];
//    return self;
//}

//- (instancetype)initMock
//{
//    self = nil;
//    NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
//    return date;
//}

- (instancetype)initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(NSTimeInterval)secs
{
    return [self initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + secs];
}

- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceNow
{
    NSTimeInterval t = [self timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    return t - [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
}

@end
```

Comment: Can't you use the factory methods in your code (e.g. `[NSDate date]`) which are easily mocked?

Comment: Not every part of the code uses [NSDate date]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSDate` has to important characteristics:

- It is a class cluster
- It is immutable

In such a case, `+alloc` returns only a placeholder and you send `-init…` to that placeholder (of class `__NSPlaceholderDate`). Replacing `-init` (`NSDate`) has no effect, if `-init` (`__NSPlaceholderDate` or NSWhatever is implemented.)

This is, because `+alloc` cannot decide which (private) subclass to choose, because it has no parameters. (They are passed at the `-init…`.)

You can

- simply replace `-init` of `__NSPlaceholderDate`
- replace `-init` of what `+alloc` returns.
- replace `+alloc` to return your private placeholder and overwrite `-init` in it.

Comment: how exactly to replace init of NSPlaceholderDate ?  Like this ? ```class_getInstanceMethod(NSClassFromString(@"__NSPlaceholderDate"), @selector(init)); ```

Comment: This gets an instance method. Look for `class_replaceMethod()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need mock dates e.g. in your tests, consider instantiating the `NSDate` objects with the [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and replacing the factory for production or tests. This way only your own classes end up with the mock dates and you don't have to worry about accidentally replacing methods that may be used by Apple's frameworks.